# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'LRNGrad' on Android

Tags: tensorflow

I developed some Tensorflow-based C++ application that run successfully on Linux. Now I'm trying to developed Android version but I can't fix the following error: **Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'LRNGrad' with these attrs. Registered kernels:**

```
    [[Node: gradients/localresponsenorm1_grad/LRNGrad = 
LRNGrad[T=DT_FLOAT, alpha=0.0001, beta=0.5, bias=2, depth_radius=5]
(gradients/maxpool1_grad/MaxPoolGrad,conv2d2, localresponsenorm1)]]
```

I've added to Android Build all kernels available for Android by means of `//tensorflow/core/kernels:android_all_ops` in `core/kernels/BUILD` and even included `lrn_op.cc` to build separately but there is no effect.

My Linux build works fine. What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does it actually say `<no registered kernels>` in your output? I'm assuming this just got interpreted as HTML and rendered invisible.

Which library are you depending on on for your Android app? tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib should already contain this kernel. (android_all_ops is not actually used for any targets internal to TensorFlow, which is somewhat misleading).

Comment: There is no `<no registered kernels>` in my logcat output. I'm assuming that the `LRNGrad` kernel is already registered bacause when I commented its registration in `/core/ops/nn_ops.cc` I got `<no registered kernels>` message. My Android app depending on `tensorflow/core:android_tensorflow_lib`. Generally, I used `tensorflow/examples/android` as a template for my app.